# aws cloudfront signed urls and mediapackage

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, signed-url, aws-mediapackage

I'm using aws mediapackage and aws cloudfront to serving video on demand.
Due to the security reasons, I have have cdn authorization for my packaging group in mediapackage and it works which means all assets are available only from cloudfront. But for more security, i need to restrict access by using signed urls. when i enable this feature in cloudfront console, restriction works fine and my urls return 403 forbidden. when i sign a url, i won't receive 403 but the problem is streaming is not working anymore. which means i have below error in my browser's console:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://xxxxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net/out/v1/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.m3u8' from origin '127.0.0.1:8000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Answer (score 0):

**CORS policy** is irrelevant here. I think the main issue is that the player you are using is not requesting child manifest with signed URL or the signature used in the signed URL is invalid.

> Can you check URL requesting
> "https://xxxxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net/out/v1/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.m3u8" in the
> debug mode whether it includes Expires, signature and Key-Pair-Id

Each manifest and segments has a different base URL. This means the signature used in the signed URL is different. You have to make sure your player uses the correct signature when playback

Thanks,
Sam